# SEM or path analysis: Latent vars with individual items as indicators, or composite scores as observed vars?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, composite

I am unsure which analysis is more appropriate out of path analysis or SEM (Structural equation modelling). I am looking at the relationships between a number of variables which have been measured by scales (i.e. Extraversion & Neuroticism subscales of the BFI, Self-Liking subscale of the SLSC-R, etc.)

I believe I have two choices:

1. Conduct a SEM using each individual question/item as an indicator of the factor which the subscale represents. The scales I'm using vary from 4 items to 10 items. Measurement error is controlled but model fit might be more difficult due to greater complexity.
2. Conduct a path analysis by using the composite scores of the subscales as the observed variables and conduct a path anaysis only. Assumption of no measurement error

Thanks for your advice.